# Find the area of a triangle formed by vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

**Question**

Find the area of a triangle formed by vectors ⃗ and ⃗, if ⃗ = $\vec {A}+2\vec {B}$, ⃗ = $2\vec {A} - \vec {B}$ where |$\vec {A}$| = 3, |$\vec {B}$| = 4, and the angle between $\vec {A}$ and $\vec {B}$ is π/6

I can't figure out how to find it without vectors components.

Comment: Try expressing $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ as $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$, respectively, and use these values to obtain expression for the components of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. See if you can find an explicit formula for the area of the triangle using these values. Then, use the information you have about $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ to finish the computation (maybe using the formula $\vec A \cdot \vec B = \|\vec A\|\|\vec B\|\cos \theta$...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  area is $$Ar=\frac{1}{2} |\vec x \times \vec y|= \frac{1}{2}|(\vec A +2 \vec B) \times (2\vec A- \vec B)]|= \frac{1}{2}|2 \vec B \times \vec A -\vec A \times \vec B]|=\frac{3}{2} |\vec A \times \vec B| =\frac{3}{2} |A||B| |\hat n|\sin(\pi/6)= 9 $$

Here we have used $\vec A \times \vec A=0$, $\vec A \times \vec B=-\vec B \times \vec A$ and that $|\hat n|=1$.

Comment: Your explanation is clear and understandable. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IceApinon, Welcome now you accept the answer.